# Return data using an https call with nodejs in a lambda function

Tags: node.js, https, aws-lambda

I am trying to set up an HTTPS call inside my lambda function. I have gone through a number of tutorials but I obviously don't understand it well enough.

I am just using a basic example to a chuck norris jokes API.

```js
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'});

const https = require('https');

let url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random"

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {


    function httpsCall() {
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const options = {
                host: 'api.chucknorris.io',
                path: '/jokes/random',
                port: 443,
                method: 'GET'
            };
    
            const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
              resolve('Success');
            });
    
            req.on('error', (e) => {
              reject(e.message);
            });
    
            // send the request
            req.write('');
            req.end();
        });
    }
    
    console.log(await httpsCall())
    // httpsCall().then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => console.log(data))

};
```

Best I can get is for it to return "Success"
Using the .then() chaining doesn't produce any results, neither does trying to work with the "res" return in the reslove function.

I have no idea what else to try...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `response.end` event to resolve the promise.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-2' });

const https = require('https');

let url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random"

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {


  async function httpsCall() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const options = {
        host: 'api.chucknorris.io',
        path: '/jokes/random',
        port: 443,
        method: 'GET'
      };

      const req = https.request(options, (res) => {

        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          body += chunk;
        })

        res.on('end', () => {
          resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        })
      });

      req.on('error', (e) => {
        reject(e.message);
      });

      // send the request
      req.write('');
      req.end();
    });
  }
  console.log(await httpsCall())
  // httpsCall().then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
};
```

Comment: if you see my answer, i have removed the word "Sucess" from the code